# Как рекурсивно добавить элементы массива в childrens?

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

```
const arr = [{id: 1, name: '...'}, {id: 2, name: '...'}, {id: 3, name: '...'}]
```

Получить

```
[{id: 1, name: '...', childrens: [{id: 2, name: '...', childrens: [{id: 3, name: '...'}] } ] }];
```

Comment: в данном случае рекурсия не нужна достаточно цикла в обратную сторону

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хорошо, спасибо